# includegraphics choosing pdf instead of eps

Tags: pdftex, pdf, eps, bounding-box

I previously posted this on stackoverflow.com where it was suggested that I post it here. So apologies in advance for cross-posting.

I am using LaTeX in ubuntu 10.04 to build a TeX file that uses `\includegraphics`. I am not specifying the file extension to allow latex to auto decide. I have both `.pdf` and `.eps` files for each image I am including.

My problem is that if I build with `pdflatex` everything works. However if I build with `latex` I get errors of the form:

```
 ! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in images/DetailedArch.pdf
 (no BoundingBox).
```

I assumed that running `latex` would automatically choose the EPS version of the file. If I specify the `.eps` extension in the `\includegraphics` command everything works fine. I have tried various options such as using `\ifpdf` but have failed to find a solution.

One point that I notice is that in Ubuntu 10.04 `latex` is a link to `pdftex` -- not sure if this is part of the issue.

Comment: Did you specify the driver?, as in \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}. As a rule of thumb, I always use the form above and specify the extension .eps. No problems so far.

Comment: `...in Ubuntu 10.04 latex is a link to pdftex...` That pretty much seems to be the reason why.

Comment: @Zhenya I think your solution is to specify the file extension (correct me if I am wrong). This is not a solution for me since I want to be able to compile the same latex file using latex and pdftex without changing the latex file.

Comment: Thanks @yoda, any ideas why latex would link to pdftex. Also I would have thought that if pdflatex can extract the bounding box from the pdf file then pdftex should be able to achieve the same. Obviously not...

Comment: @user: Did you try specifying [dvips]{graphicx} in the preamble and not specifying the extension? Anyway, if you always keep files as eps and specify the extension, you'll be able to compile in both pdftex and latex.

Comment: @Zhenya: yes I tried this but it still defaults to including pdf. The reason I need to do it this way (i.e. not including the file extension) is that the code is part of a .cls file for creating thesis documents. The front page of the thesis has a logo which I have saved in both eps and pdf. What I am trying to achieve is, when some uses the cls file, that it automatically includes the appropriate logo file. I don't want the client to have to specify the location of the file (or it's extension) or obviously to have to switch cls files depending on whether they use pdflatex or latex.

Comment: Note: the previous post on stackoverflow can be viewed at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417868/latex-includegraphics-choosing-pdf-instead-of-eps
In case you want to have a look at previous comments/discussion.

Comment: Are you adding an extension to the file name in the `\includegraphics` line? (You should not.)

Comment: @johnmcd Welcome to TeX-SE! Usually it's best not to cross-post like this -- if your question is better served on another place, a moderator could help you migrate it, along with all comments and answers it had accumulated. You do need a tiny bit of reputation in order to flag for moderation attention (15, IIRC), and then you can just use the "flag" link under your question.

Comment: What you are doing is supposed to work. Please construct a minimal example that demonstrates the problem and edit it into your question.

Comment: @martin-tapankov My apologies for this, I will be more careful in the future. However I have flagged on the other post that the discussion has moved to this page.

Comment: The issue was caused by a configuration error and got solved by the OP himself. See the OP's comment below my answer. Closed as "too localized" because of this.

Comment: @yoda: No, that's normal. `latex` is nowadays `pdflatex` in DVI mode. Executables which act differently depending on the name used to execute them (e.g. over symlinks) are common under Linux.

Comment: @Zhenya: *Please*, the driver should *not* be specified explicitly. Doing so is often causing more harm than good. Also the auto-detection works usually very good.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this is to declare the graphics extension to be used using `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions` and do not supply an extension when including the image:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
  \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}
\else
  \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
\fi

% In the document:
\includegraphics{image_name}%  no extension!
```

I personally gave up on this dual compilation stuff and only use `pdflatex` since years. There are some packages which help you if you need PS-related stuff.

Comment: @Martin: With the standard settings on a modern TeX system, EPS _versus_ PDF selection is automatic provided graphics are included without extension. So messing with `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions` should not be needed.

Comment: @Joseph: Oh, yeah, you are right. I know remember using the above code mostly to change the order of extensions, e.g. have PNG before JPG because it is lossless.

Comment: I have tried the above but it didn't work i.e. when I run latex it still includes the pdf file but without. I think the problem is related to the fact that on my system Ubuntu 10.04 64 bit /usr/bin/latex is just a link to /usr/bin/pdftex. The package that "owns" /usr/bin/latex is texlive-latex-base.

I will construct an example as suggested and post it.

Comment: @johnmcd: `latex` as symlink to `pdftex` is normal. This simply uses `pdflatex` in DVI mode, which is the way the modern LaTeX does it. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem, i.e. causes this behavior. Without it we can only guess what's wrong.

Comment: In trying to construct a minimal solution I have, somewhat embarrassingly, solved the problem. Basically I am using a thesis class file which referenced a common macros file that had built up within our group over the past number of years. I have just realised that someone had (quite stupidly) inserted \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf} in the middle of that macro file.

Thanks for the help, and apologies for not having spotted this myself earlier.

Comment: @johnmcd: ;-) This happens more often than you think and is one of the main reason we ask for a MWE. I will close the question as "too localized" then.

Comment: @Martin-Scharrer thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

The extensions and their order are declared in the driver file of the graphics package. The standard dvips driver e.g. contains

```
\def\Gin@extensions{.eps,.ps,.eps.gz,.ps.gz,.eps.Z}
```

And this means that if this driver is used `.pdf` graphics will not be used.

Which driver your document use depends on your document and your system. Make a minimal example that demonstrates your problem and show it to us along with the log-file of the latex run.